# Field#getAnnotation() not working with own annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

My annotation looks like this:

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface IsCrossSellingRevelant
{
    boolean value() default true;
}
```

My ModelClass look like this

```
public abstract class A {
    @IsCrossSellingRevelant(true)
    protected String someAnnotatedFiled;
    protected String someFiled;
}

public class B extends A {
    private String irrelevant;
}
```

Now I have a method that should give me alle annotated fields in the class hierarchy

```
A object = new B();

Class<?> classIterator = object.getClass().getSuperclass();

do
{
    for (Field field : classIterator.getDeclaredFields())
    {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        IsCrossSellingRevelant isRelevant = field.getAnnotation(IsCrossSellingRevelant.class);
        Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        Annotation[] annotations2 = field.getAnnotations();
    }

    classIterator = classIterator.getSuperclass();
}
while (classIterator != Object.class);
```

But the Arrays `annotations` and `annotations2` are empty and `isRelevant` in every case what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the [@Retention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html) annotation on your annotation, setting the [@Retention.value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html) to [RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#RUNTIME) like this:

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IsCrossSellingRevelant
{
  boolean value() default true;
}
```